# How to check if an variable in Javascript is defined in another Javascript file and display an alert if it isn't?

Tags: javascript

I have an JavaScript framework for making some HTML5 elements work in older browsers and letting users create their own elements. The function for an user to create their own element is used on another Javascript file, for example:

```
element('myElement').appendStyleColor('red').type('text');
```

For making sure the user is creating the element with my framework, I've created a variable that the user defines at the end of their file. For example:

```
using = "myFramework";
```

I had to create a test to display an alert if the variable 'using' doesn't have the value 'myFramework', but I can't get the test to work, because if the test goes it only looks in the myFramework.js file and not in the user's JavaScript file like the script.js file or the application.js file.

My code is as followed:

```
if (using !== "myFramework") {
     alert("The value 'myFramework' is not defined in the 'using' variable.")   
}
```

P.S : My Framework is not the real name of the framework.

** I do not want to use jQuery **

Comment: Your check will only work if your script is included *after* the other files.  It can't check for variables added in the future.

Comment: You probably want to look into using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: It's not about which file it looks in but at what else is already loaded when that condition is executed

Comment: Please have a look at my answer, I believe that you took the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For making sure the user is creating the element with my framework,
>   I've created a variable that the user defines at the end of their
>   file.

Have a global `using` variable is a poor way to monitor if the element was created with your framework or not. It's extremely unreliable and adds complexity to the client code. Even if that `using` variable was defined, there's nothing telling you they really used the `element` function to manipulate their elements. Also, it's a very bad practice to pollute the global namespace with additionnal globals.

Anyway, I am not sure why it's of any interest to have that knowledge, but you could simply set an attribute on the element it-self it it's ever passed/created to/by the `element` function.

To make it simple, let's say that you have an `element` function that takes a `tagName` as argument and returns a wrapped version of the element.

E.g.

```
var element = (function () {
    var elCount = 0;

    function element(tagName) {
        return new ElementWrapper(document.createElement(tagName));
    }

    function ElementWrapper(el) {
        this.el = el;
        this.el.setAttribute('data-my-framework', ++elCount);
    }

    return element;

})();
```

That means you can use `someDOMEl.hasAttribute('data-my-framework')` to know if the element was created with the `element` function or not. Obviously the client code could always remove the attribute, but then there's nothing you can do.

```
console.log(element('div').el.getAttribute('data-my-framework')); //1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this check using an `onload` event. This makes sure all the content is loaded and the variable would be set:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    if (using !== "myFramework") {
       alert("The value 'myFramework' is not defined in the 'using' variable.");
    }
 }
```

Comment: This still doesn't help me with the problem.